# iSightAudio.plugin error when playing video using MediaPlayer

Tags: iphone, media-player

I am working on creating a simple iPhone app that plays a movie via URL. When I Build&Run to test in the simulator, it works fine; as soon as I start playing the movie, I get the following message in the console:

```
[1757:4b03] Cannot find executable for CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x820ffe0 
            </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/iSightAudio.plugin> 
            (not loaded)
[1757:4b03] Cannot find function pointer iSightAudioNewPlugIn for 
            factory 9BE7661E-8AEF-11D7-8692-000A959F49B0 in 
            CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x820ffe0 
            </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/iSightAudio.plugin> 
            (not loaded)
```

I don't get this error on other programs, so I assume it has something to do with this specific program, which uses the MediaPlayer.framework.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Same error here (macbook under Snow Leopard) for an other program (espeak at http://espeak.sourceforge.net/download.html). I suspect it's due to the system restauration I've done last week with Time Machine, since this error didn't occur before. You may test your app on some other mac.